# Change notification default sound to a custom one using Ionic - Cordova-plugin-push with FCM

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I added my custom sound in my res folder and in my assets folder as mp3:

```
assets/ringtone/alert_signal.mp3
app/src/main/res/raw/alert_signal.mp3
```

I followed the documentation for the plugin and it say to also add this line in config.xml:

```
<resource-file src="src/assets/ringtone/alert_signal.mp3" target="app/src/main/res/raw/alert_signal.mp3" />
```

I also added this line in my app.component:

```
  initPushNotification() {
    const push = PushNotification.init({
      android: {
        sound: 'alert_signal',
      },
      ios: {
          alert: 'true',
          badge: true,
          sound: 'false'
      },
      windows: {}
    });
```

And this is the payload on how I send the push notification:

```
var message = {
  data: {
    "title": "Title",
    "body": "Body",
    "soundname": "alert_signal",
   }
}
```

With all the modifications above I still am not hearing my alert_signal sound when I receive a notification in my phone.

I see this in my Android Studio Logcat:

```
 Sound URL: android.resource://io.ionic.starter/raw/alert_signal
```

I tried following the instructions by this link:

https://github.com/havesource/cordova-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#sound

It does not work. I also tried this line:

`"soundname": "ringtone"` also
`"soundname": "default" or "soundname": ""`

I also tried in different devices still the same outcome!
I still get the system notification sound!

**UPDATE**

I did a clean re-build of the project and everything is working fine now :)